# Implement Java Web Server with database, GCM and background threads

Tags: java, multithreading, web-services

I am trying to create a web server that provides web service functions, communicates with android devices using GCM, uses a database and probably also has some background work to do.

I am currently unsure on the architecture of such a server.
I know how to create a simple web service, but have not found tutorials or descriptions that go beyond simple "Hello World" examples. As far as i know i can create a class with the @WebService annotation, and once deployed to e.G. Tomcat the server will create at least one instance of this class and provide the annoteted functions in this class as web services.

Now i wonder how to best implement database connection. From what i know the server would create an instance of this class for every request, wich will be garbage collected once the connection is closed. Since the web server needs the database for nearly every function it provides i think it would not be a good idea to create a database connection for every instance, but rather use a global connection to query the database.
From what i found out so far this could be achieved by injecting a class that handles the database connection as @Resource or @Singleton into the web service class.
But is this the proper way to do this ? Or am i worring too much and just creating a new database connection for each request is fine ?

Then i want to send GCM messages (the simple POST ones using the HTML google server), so i would probably create a controller or manager class to handle these requests. Would this also be injected as a @Resource or @Singleton into the web service class ?

And last but not least the server probably has to do some work periodicaly, wich would be some kind of background thread, that is independant of the requests the web service is recieving. Here i am at a loss on how to do this. A web service does not have a main() method i am aware of, so i am unsure on how to create this.

Can anyone give me a guick overview on how to design such a web server or can point me to documentation that describe on how to achieve this ?
All i found so far were simple examples that don't cover advanced stuff like this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you have 3 questions/problems.

1. How to create a Webservice
2. How to manage database connections
3. Execute batch process

All of this, in the same App. First of all, I should advice you to split into 2 app, one for consume (Web Services) and another for batch processing, including push notifications (IMHO). But lets go one step at a time.

**1. Webservice**: It's depends on the framework you choose. I usually made a choice between Spring-MVC or Jersey

**2. How to manage database connections** When you are querying a database, you usually don't want to open and close connections crazily. You want to use a connection pool. In a connection pool you'll ask for an open connection, will use it, and will free it when you are done. Normally, a connection pool is managed por the application server. If you want to manage the connections manually, you have to use a singleton to centralise acquiring and releasing.

**3. Execute batch process** You probably should use a singleton to manage batch process. This job manager will launch the job executions on other threads

Don't know if that answers your question/concern.. please let me know.

Comment: I know hot to create a web service. Was using JAX-WS server created in NetBeans. What i like to know is how to get the database connection and the background worker into this too. The push notifications can't be in another application because they are a direct result of web service calls from an android device.

Comment: To clarify it a bit: android devices should be able to connect to the web service, i need database to handle accounts and some data, and the server then informs some other android devices that something has happened. For the sake of an example lets assume i want to log into an account with the android device (so check in database if user is valid) then send a message to server, which looks up some other devices in the database and then sends a GCM to these, that a message is availiable.

Answer (score 0):

Ryu,

I found myself in a similar **[scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26735941/push-notifications-from-a-web-service)**. After going through the webs for over 2 days, I stumbled upon this solution of running a background thread which is triggered during the initialization of a servlet(init method).

Perhaps you can give this a shot and let me know if it works for you.

Here's the link which has an example to try - http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/servlet/ch03_05.htm

Cheers!