# PUSH Notifications from a Web service

Tags: java, web-services, rest, web-applications, push-notification

I have a web service that stores locations of a mobile user in the DB periodically. I now want to try sending `push` notifications from the web service to the **Android** app. I understand that this can be achieved using **GCM for Android**.

However, I am not sure how I can run a process that continuously monitors the DB for a condition. Can somebody suggest how I can achieve this?

Will creating a `thread` to do the monitoring task in the `constructor` of the web service help to maintain a constant monitor?

P.S: At the moment I am just starting a thread which will check the DB for the condition I need when the app calls the store method and then sends `POST` request to GCM server to push notifications if the condition is satisfied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps to accomplish this task -

1. Create a `servlet` and register it in the deployment descriptor
2. Override the `init` method of the **servlet**
3. Create a thread and start it in the `init` method. Use a `while` loop to execute infinitely to do the monitoring task
4. Most important - force the **servlet** initialization during server startup by adding the following line to the deployment descriptor. Info at this link - http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/Initialization-at-startup-as-opposed-to-first-request-td5164440.html